# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback mysqli

Tags: php

I have this script trying to put array into mysqli_stmt_bind_param, I googled around and found this solution, however, the code doesn't seems to be working properly. I received no results from database and a warning.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
```

Here is my code:-

```
$sql_param = array();
    $params = array();

    $query = "SELECT campname,url,views,leads,subs,country,affid FROM camp WHERE";

if (isset($_POST['fromdatetime']) && isset($_POST['todatetime'])) {
    $datefrom = $_POST['fromdatetime'].":00";
    $dateto = $_POST['todatetime'].":59";

    $sql_param[] = $datefrom;
    $sql_param[] = $dateto;
    $bindparam = "ss";
    $query .= "datevisit between (?) AND (?)";
}

if (isset($_POST['affidcode'])) {
    $affidcode = $_POST['affidcode'];
    $sql_param[] = $affidcode;
    $bindparam .= "s";
    $query .= " AND affid = (?)";
}

$sql_param_count = count($sql_param);
$params[] = &$bindparam;

for($i = 0; $i < $sql_param_count; $i++) {
      $params[] = &$sql_param[$i];
    }

    /* create a prepared statement */
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'mysqli_stmt_bind_param'), $params); 

    /* execute query */
    $status = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call\_user\_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366249/call-user-func-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try change `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` to `bind_param`.

Comment: @brevis I did too, still same warning and display no result.

Comment: Here is another example http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#89171

Comment: @brevis Tried too... but I received this:-
`Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `$stmt` is valid `mysqli_stmt` object (not `false`) after this block:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
```

Then try this:

```
array_unshift($params, $stmt);
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $params);
```

Comment: Done, but another problem arises.... `mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given`

Comment: Check `$stmt` after `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);` line. If it is `false` – something wrong in SQL.

Comment: Nice! The query is missing white space end of the query. Thanks!