# How to write a valid callback for preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, ''s:'.strlen('$2').':&quot;$2&quot;;'',

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback, php-7.3

In my config.php I have this old PHP5 function that I have tried to update for use in PHP7, but this error and warning is spoiling things:

> PHP Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, ''s:'.strlen('$2').':"$2";'', to be a valid callback

Could someone please advise how to make it a valid callback? Many thanks in advance for your help.

The function missing the valid callback is:

```php
function __unserialize( $sObject ) {
$__ret = preg_replace_callback( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $sObject );
return unserialize( $__ret );
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366249/call-user-func-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback

Answer (score 1):

This code appears to be very naively attempting to fix a serialization bug. Whenever I've seen that, it was always because someone performed a database search-and-replace blindly and PHP is very particular about its storage format.

For, I would say just see if you can get away with removing the regex, maybe it isn't needed anymore. Watch your logs and see if you see any notices.

```php
function __unserialize( $sObject ) {
    return unserialize( $sObject );
}
```

If that doesn't work, here is a version that does on very simple objects but has some caveats to be aware of:

```php
function __unserialize($sObject)
{
    $__ret = preg_replace_callback(
        '!s:(?<length>\d+):"(?<value>.*?)";!',
        static function ($matches) {
            return 's:' . strlen($matches['value']) . ':"' . $matches['value'] . '";';
        },
        $sObject
    );
    return unserialize($__ret);
}
```

This can be tested with:

```php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->test = 'test';

$before = serialize($obj);
$after = __unserialize($before);

echo $before, PHP_EOL;

print_r($after);
```

In PHP, the string `test` string is serialized as:

```php
s:4:"test"
```

where the first digit is the length of the string followed by the actual string. If the length doesn't match, that's where things get bad and that's what your code was trying to fix. I say your code does it naively because there are edge cases that it can't handle, such as this:

```php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->test = 'test";';

$before = serialize($obj);
$after = __unserialize($before);
```

But, if it worked in the past, maybe those edge cases don't exist.

Comment: Chris, thank you very much for helping out. Your first suggestion removing regex was spot on, no more errors and code running smoothly. Thank you!

Comment: Also your 2nd solution, with the new version of the piece of code works OK too, no errors and code running OK, Thank you!